# cmd copy everything except files with a certain extension

Tags: cmd, xcopy

I want to copy all contents of a folder into one of it's subfolders (dist) except for .ts files and dist itself:

```
/root
   /models
       User.js
       User.ts
   .env
```

should become:

```
/root
    /dist
        /models
            User.js
        .env
    /models
        User.js
        User.ts
    .env
```

I know that I can use xcopy to copy files/folders recursively, but I don't know how to exclude the .ts files and dist folder

Comment: Take a look at the `/EXCLUDE` option of [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), or even better, at [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)'s `/XF` option...

Comment: @aschipfl thanks for the hint. This works perfectly: robocopy ./ ./dist /XF *.ts /XD ./dist